# Simple jQuery quiz does not execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code. It is supposed to be a simple quiz with just one question and another pop up window with the correct answer, if answered wrong.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jsx"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#results").click(function() {                
        if (!$("input[@name=q1]:checked").val()) {            
          alert("You're not done yet!");        
        }        
        else {            
          var cat1name = "1";            
          var cat2name = "None";                                  
          var cat1 = ($("input[@name=q1]:checked").val() != "a"); 
          var cat2 = (!cat1); var categories = [];                        
          if (cat1) {
            categories.push(cat1name);
          }
          if (cat2) {
            categories.push(cat2name);
          }
          var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';                     
          $("#categorylist").text(catStr);                        
          $("#categorylist").show("slow");            
          if (cat1) {
            $("#category1").show("slow");
          }            
          if (cat2) {
            $("#category2").show("slow");
          }
          $("#closing").show("slow");
        }
      });
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ... some CSS
    ... the question look like this:
    <p class="question">1. What is the answer to this question?</p>        
    <ul class="answers">            
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a"><label for="q1a">Answer 1</label><br/>          
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="b" id="q1b"><label for="q1b">Answer 2</label><br/>            
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="c" id="q1c"><label for="q1c">Answer 3</label><br/>            
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="d" id="q1d"><label for="q1d">Answer 4</label><br/>       
    </ul>          
    <br/>
    <div id="results">            
      Show me the answers!       
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Code is from this site http://www.hungrypiranha.org/make-a-website/html-quiz.

I want to adapt the code and have just one question. Copying and pasting the code with the 10 samplequestions works fine. But as soon as I shorten the code, it does not work. Clicking on the answere button does not do anything. What do I oversee?

Comment: If you format your code (e.g. in a JSFiddle) you will see you have mismatching braces at the end. From `alert(catStr);` onwards. I have deleted the answer showing that as some trigger-happy user negged it before I finished typing!

Comment: Try to format your code a bit better. `if (cat2) { $("#category2").show("slow"); };                                   
{ $("#closing").show("slow"); };
}
     });});


{            
alert(catStr);        
} 
    });});` is an absolute mess

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks. I see it now. I guess I stared to long at it. Never worked with jQuery or JS thus I am not used to the syntax. I guess I get along from here! thanks!

Comment: I will restore my answer... Only need one upvote to compensate for the monkey that down-voted it :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Ill accept it when the three mins are over!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you format your code (e.g. in a JSFiddle) you will see you have mismatching braces at the end. From `alert(catStr);` onwards.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#results").click(function () {

        if (!$("input[@name=q1]:checked").val()

        ) {
            alert("You're not done yet!");
        } else {
            var cat1name = "1";
            var cat2name = "None";


            var cat1 = ($("input[@name=q1]:checked").val() != "a");

            var cat2 = (!cat1);
            var categories = [];

            if (cat1) {
                categories.push(cat1name)
            };
            if (cat2) {
                categories.push(cat2name)
            };


            var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';
            $("#categorylist").text(catStr);
            $("#categorylist").show("slow");

            if (cat1) {
                $("#category1").show("slow");
            };
            if (cat2) {
                $("#category2").show("slow");
            }; {
                $("#closing").show("slow");
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Suggest you use an editor that provides good formatting of your code as it is easy to get lost in a sea of braces :)

Comment: WTF... Wait for the answer to settle before negging!

Comment: Guess I need another 5 negs before it is worth while deleting this again :) To the cowardly secret downvoters I say :P